# Netbeans C++ Macro unecpected token: { with Macro from PEGTL library

Tags: c++, netbeans, syntax-highlighting, netbeans-8.2

I stumbled across some behaviour that occours in conjunction with the C++11 PEG library [PEGTL](https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL). Unfortunatly I'm not capable to reproduce this behaviour outside the libraries function/templates. This occured with Netbeans

A minimal example would look like this:

```
include <tao/pegtl.hpp>
using namespace tao::TAOCPP_PEGTL_NAMESPACE;

struct foo : istring<'f','o','o'> {};
struct bar : TAOCPP_PEGTL_ISTRING("foo") {};
struct foo2 : istring<'f','o','o'> {};
```

TAOCPP_PEGTL_ISTRING is a macro definition, that expands to istring<>, so TAOCPP_PEGTL_ISTRING("foo") is the same as istring<'f','o','o'>.
GCC doesn't have a problem with that, but as soon as I try to use this Macro, it says

```
unexpected token: {
unexpected token: }
unknown identifier bar
```

and every following line gets errors too.

- the struct foo line is fine
- the struct bar line is where the error occurs
- struct foo2 would be fine, but since the struct bar line generated an error, it's also displaying an error

[image: highlighted error]

[image: highlighted error message box]

Here is my System/Netbeans information:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609270201)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_101; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.101-b13
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_101-b13
System: Linux version 4.13.0-36-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
```

Comment: Do you have any compilation errors or is this just your IDE and C++ trying to outwit each other?

Comment: It's just the IDE, gcc has no problems at all, it just breaks syntax highlighting and auto completion beyond the line I used the Macro.